# CountDown Timer OnTick method Not Working when I give Time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timer, countdown

```
I'm Running one count down timer for 15 minutes which is equals to 100%,
```

When I'm in the app it's fine working for me.
What i'm doing is when i'm closing the app I'm saving start time and opening the app taking current time and calculating the remaining time.
 I'm giving the remaining time to ontick method before starting the countdown timer. on the first tick it's showing correct but for the next tick,It's starting from 15 minutes. Can anyone tell why it's happenning

```
 countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(900000, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    activity?.runOnUiThread {
                        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)
                        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))

                        val progress = 100 - ((((minutes / 15f) + (seconds / 900f)) * 100).toInt())

                        if (progress == 100) {
                            countDownTimer.cancel()
                            batteryHealthView.hideProgress()
                        }
                        saveData(progress, percentageString)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    activity?.runOnUiThread {
                        countDownTimer.cancel()
                    }
                }
            }
            if (timeLeft!! > 0) {
                countDownTimer.onTick(timeLeft)
            }
            countDownTimer.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share code how you are calling **CountDownTimer(900000, 1000)**  Its seems you are using 900000 each time, Instead you need to re calculate remain time and pass that time in method call.

Comment: The entire code I'm just calling in a normal method, the countdown variable i declared as  ( private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer) and the method i'm calling is (   fun countDownTimer(activity: FragmentActivity?, batteryHealthView: BatteryHealthCheckView, timeLeft: Long?)) the time left is nothing but the reamining time I'm passing and each time i need to conitinue the progress instead starting from 0

Comment: You don't need to pass 900000 each time, you need to store spent time when you leave app and re calculate remaining time when you back in app and pass that time in constructure

Comment: Thanks it's worked now everytime I'm sending the remaining time and gives the correct value